# Run "gradle assemble" from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin, gradle

I have the "Gradle IDE" pugin for Eclipse. In my Gradle project, when I right-click, I can see a "Gradle" menu option.

Unfortunately, none of the options are "assemble." I want to run the command-line equivalent of `gradle assemble` from within Eclipse. (This is because I have an Android project which depends on my Gradle project, and I can't automagically make Eclipse do this on every run of the Android project.)

So how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

D'oh. I just saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1560820/210780), which points to using `External Tools` to launch Gradle.

[image]

I'll leave this here for any future readers.

Comment: It is not clear how to use `External Tools` from this screenshot.

Comment: @PaulVerest I assume someone using Gradle or Eclipse would know how to use `External Tools` (I learned it here without much trouble). Is there something you got stuck on, or some additional clarification you feel is necessary?